# Inserting a tag around a specific character in a title

Tags: javascript, replace, tags

I need to replace 'No' with 'N<sup>o</sup>' inside an h1 heading using vanilla javascript. So in a nutshell I would like to find the h1 tag by searching for it's class '.product__title', search the text inside the h1 tag and find every instance of 'No' and then wrap a sup tag around the 'o', like below

```
N<sup>o</sup>
```

And example of the heading could be 'Table N<sup>o</sup> 04'

This is the code that I have tried, which finds and replaces the word - but I'm unable to insert the sub tag around the 'o', without the browser actually rendering the sub tag as text and not html.

```
var html = document.querySelector('.product__title');
  var walker = document.createTreeWalker(html, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
  var node;
  while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/No/, 'N<sup>o</sup>')
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. The above code is from a tutorial I found searching around, so it's not my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("h1.product__title")]
  .forEach(h1 => h1.innerHTML = h1.textContent.replace("No ","N<sup>o</sup> "))
```

```html
<h1 class="product__title">Table No 04</h1>
<h1 class="product__title">Table No 05</h1>
```